# postgresql change encode to hex for specific columns content in table

Tags: database, postgresql

Im trying to update all the values in 2 particular columns for two different tables we have to HEX so far without luck in our PostgreSQL 8.4.7 on Centos.

Here are the two columns types and the table name they belong too:

-node_id is a smallint column default 1. this belongs to table1
-value is a bytea column that belongs to table2

I can do a select on table2 for the value:bytea column with the following selec:

SELECT encode(value::bytea, 'hex') FROM table2;

But this syntax does not work for table1 node_id:smallint column.

I've try the following commands without luck in and effort to change the values of the columns to hex on the respective tables.

ALTER TABLE table2 SET value TO 'hex';

ALTER TABLE table2 MODIFY value TO 'hex';

UPDATE table1 (value::bytea, 'hex');

UPDATE tbl table2 SET value::bytea TO 'hex';

SET encode(value::bytea, 'hex') FROM table2;

There is any proper way to do this in a one command like the above?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hard to read I think... Do you want to change the data type of `table1.node_id` to `bytea` or do you want to select a hexadecimal representation of `table1.node_id`?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem with the following command:

CREATE TABLE "name" AS select *, encode(value, 'hex') as "column_name" from "table";